# Find expectation/variance of Random vector with uniform distribution on the cube ${[- \sqrt 3, \sqrt3]}^m$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, vectors, random-variables, expectation

> Let $Y = (Y_1,Y_2,\ldots , Y_m)$ be a random vector with uniform distribution on the cube ${[- \sqrt 3, \sqrt3]}^m$.
>
> 1) Prove that the Y_i are mutually independent.
>
> 2) What is $E(Y_i)$, $E(Y_i^2)$, $Var(Y_i^2)$?
>
> 3) Let $\left\lVert Y\right\rVert$ = $\sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i^2}$ represent distance from Y to origin. Verify that $$E(|\left\lVert Y\right\rVert - \sqrt m|^2)<1,$$ then verify $$P(\left\lVert Y\right\rVert-\sqrt m>s)>\frac 1 {s^2}$$ for $s>0$.

For 2) So I think Y_i should equal to $E(Y_1)+...+E(Y_m)$ since it is unfiorm distribution buthow do I find $E(Y_1)$? and what do i do for $E(Y_1^2)$ do I just do $E(Y_1)^2$ since they should be independent? but I do not know how to prove 1). Any hint would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: For (2), just consider the mean, second moment and variance of a uniform distribution on $[-\sqrt 3 , \sqrt 3]$

Comment: I wrote an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446084/distance-from-the-centre-of-a-n-cube-as-n-rightarrow-infty/2446572#2446572) to a similar problem.  You might just have to scale it up.